# replace all digits BEFORE the first occurence of an alphabet in a string in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I'm trying to find a regular expression to replace all digits BEFORE the first occurence of an alphabet in a string in R using 'gsub'
I've tried looking all over. There are similar questions. But, all the reg expressions remove the first character as well.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
x <- c("84.0000000000C98","16.2000000000C98","7.5000000000C98", "8.0000000000C98", "49.8000000000C98","109.0000000000C98")


gsub('[[:digit:]].+[[:alpha:]]', '', x)

result is:
"98","98", "98" ,"98", "98" ,"98"

I want to to get this result:
"C98" "C98" "C98" "C98" "C98" "C98"
```

Comment: Is this always the only pattern you have?

Comment: It appears you wish to "...replace all digits and the decimal point BEFORE...". We're adults, "before" would be fine.

Comment: Must you use `gsub`? In view of your examples it seems that you might be able to simply match`[A-Za-z].*`. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AUqzzU/1).

Comment: Why not just replace [`^[\d.]+`](https://regex101.com/r/yfRnD1/1) with empty string.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove any char other than a letter from the string start, you can use

```r
gsub("^[^[:alpha:]]+([[:alpha:]])", "\\1", x)
```

Remove the `([[:alpha:]])` and `\\1` if you do not need to check if there is any letter after non-letters at all:

```r
gsub("^[^[:alpha:]]+", "", x)
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/rl0Wk1):

```r
x <- c("84.0000000000C98","16.2000000000C98","7.5000000000C98", "8.0000000000C98", "49.8000000000C98","109.0000000000C98")
gsub("^[^[:alpha:]]+([[:alpha:]])", "\\1", x)
# => [1] "C98" "C98" "C98" "C98" "C98" "C98"
gsub("^[^[:alpha:]]+", "", x)
# => [1] "C98" "C98" "C98" "C98" "C98" "C98"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MgGw7X/1).

Note that `([[:alpha:]])` is a capturing group with ID 1 that matches and captures the letter and `\1` in the replacement is a backreference that restores the captured text.

Answer (score 0):

Using a lookahead

```
x <- c("84.0000000000C98","16.2000000000C98",
       "7.5000000000C98","8.0000000000C98","49.8000000000C98","109.0000000000C98")

gsub("\\d.*(?=[A-Za-z])", "", x, perl = TRUE)
```

Result

```
[1] "C98" "C98" "C98" "C98" "C98" "C98"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `stringr::string_extract_all`. Then extract a string starting with any number of alphas (`[[:alpha:]]+`), followed by everything else(`.*`)

```
library(stringr)

str_extract_all(x,
                "[[:alpha:]]+.*",
                simplify = FALSE
                ) |>
    unlist()

[1] "C98" "C98" "C98" "C98" "C98" "C98"
```